# Use an image for radio button label in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, collection-select

I am trying to use the helper collection_radio_buttons to show an image as a label, and want to save the image_id to the model so that I can retrieve the url, so far I have come up with this which shows a radio button and the image_url as the label.

Something I have noticed already is that I can only click the radio button once and it then just stays in its on state:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:default_image_id, DefaultImage.all, :id, :image) %>
```

The html generated looks like so:

```
<input id="campaign_default_image_id_1" name="campaign[default_image_id]" type="radio" value="1" />
<label for="campaign_default_image_id_1">https://calcuttatest.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/default_image/image/1/vandals_portfolio.png</label>
```

How do I set this up correctly? Can I wrap the label in a image_tag ?

### Edit

So after some more research and trying to piece this together I can now render an image and a radio button, but the image is the default image I uploaded with carrierwave and not the resized :small version that I would like. Can I pass the :small version through?

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:default_image_id, DefaultImage.all, :id, :image) do |b| %>
<%= b.label { image_tag("#{b.text}") + b.radio_button } %>
```

b.text retrieves the url

```
https://calcuttatest.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/default_image/image/2/ymca_portfolio.png
```

But I would like it to prefix the filename with fancy_box_array, like so:

```
https://calcuttatest.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/default_image/image/2/fancy_box_array_ymca_portfolio.png
```

The html generated with this new code is:

```
<label for="campaign_default_image_id_1"><img alt="Vandals portfolio" src="https://calcuttatest.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/default_image/image/1/vandals_portfolio.png" />
<input id="campaign_default_image_id_1" name="campaign[default_image_id]" type="radio" value="1" /></label>
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good [reference](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons) on what you are trying to do. Try something like:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(:default_image_id, DefaultImage.all, :id, :image) do |b|
  b.label { b.radio_button + image_tag(b.object.image) }
end
```

Comment: ahh thanks so much, just had to amendimage_tag(b.object.image) to image_tag(b.object.image_url(:fancy_box_array)) as using carrierwave to retrieve images...thanks again, big help :-)