# Clickable text for radio button on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
  <%=form_for @link do |f| %>
  <%=  f.collection_radio_buttons :title, [[''] ,[''],[''],[''],  ['']], :first, :last%>

  <%= f.submit 'Save'%>
```

I'm trying to make the the emojis of my radio buttons clickable (instead of clicking the circle button I want to click the actual emoji).

Then, I want to get rid of the little circle buttons so all that can be seen is the emojis.

Finally, I want there to be some sort of visual signal when one of the emojis is chosen, such as a highlight, since the actual radio button will be gone.

I'm using the simple_form gem. I've searched for days but can't figure out how to do this. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/pPgS7/

Comment: I don't think this applies to a rails app. Does it?

Comment: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't to try emojis inserted of emoji images, For your reference

[using images in radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580256/use-an-image-for-radio-button-label-in-rails-4)